# How to build a javascript object with key/value format

Tags: javascript, object, formatting

I have a series input tag like

```
<input id="t1" value="1">
<input id="t2" value="2">
<input id="t3" value="3">
```

then I want build a javascript object as id/value format,like :

```
input:
{
   ["t1",1]
   ["t2",2]
   ["t3",3]
}
```

how can I achieve that?with which function or method?with Array?

Comment: I tried nothing,I don't have a idea at all

Comment: Well, you should at least google.

Comment: What do you need this for? The desired format from your question is not even valid javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object you describe is invalid. Assuming you mean:

```
{
   "t1":1,
   "t2":2,
   "t3":3
}
```

Just loop over the elements, and examine the id and value properties to get the data.

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var ob = {};
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  var input = inputs[i];
  ob[input.id] = input.value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your output object makes no sense, it's an object with no keys.  Assuming what you really want is:

```
{
    "t1": 1,
    "t2": 2,
    "t3": 3
}
```

You could do something like this and `inputVals` will contain the above object:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
    inputVals = {};

for (var i = 0, il = inputs.length; i < il; i++) {
    inputVals[inputs[i].id] = inputs[i].value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery serializeArray goes a long way to get what you want.

http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

It doesn't return exactly the array format that you present in the question, but it should give you something to work with.